# Prevent backspacing HTML in an iFrame.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using an iFrame as a text editor and want to ensure that the first part of the body is always a p tag. As such, I have it set so when users first click on the body it will insert

```
<p><br></p>
```

This works, unless the user holds down the backspace button. Once the user runs out of plaintext to backspace, it removes the tags above.

I have captured the event for backspace, but how can I prevent the users from removing the paragraph tags?

Comment: It's not navigation that I am trying to avoid, its backspacing away HTML.

Comment: Ah ..my bad. Mind if I ask what the intention of keeping it there is? Is it just to keep some kind of space there for aesthetic reasons. or is because you want to pass that value back?

Comment: It normalizes the way return works on all browsers, so they create a new p rather than br or div.

Comment: It guess my answer didn't help any. I would like to still help out and work with you to brainstorm ideas. It could be a learning experience for me too. Do you have a github repo or a jsbin/jsfiddle link to provide code samples from your project?

Comment: It helped, only unfortunately there were still ways to break it. I ended up just scrapping the idea and taking another route (Dealing with browser inconsistencies server side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got 11 options (I'm assuming you are using jQuery).

First, capture the keydown event, and if the value is equal to the default value, prevent the action. This will probably be inside to source html of the iframe.

```html
$('#editor').unbind('keydown').bind('keydown', function (event) {
    var doPrevent = false;
    if (event.keyCode === 8 && $('#editor').html() === '<p><br></p>'){
      
      event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Option two: just make the element that's editable a div instead.

I prefer to avoid the use of an iframe. They make things needlessly complicated (imo).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 
  function DoEdit(){
   
   var idContent = document.getElementById('idContent');
   idContent.contentEditable = "true";
   //var editor = (idContent.contentWindow || idContent.contentDocument).content.document;
   //editor.designMode = "on";
   //editor.body.contentEditable = "true";
   //editor.contentEditable = "true";
  }
  function ShowContent(){
   
   var contentValue = "<p><br></p>"+$('#idContent').html();
   alert(contentValue)
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
  
   DoEdit();
   $('#showContentBtn').click(function(){
    ShowContent();
   });
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<p><br></p>
<div style="text-align: center;margin:0 auto;width: 500px; height: 300px; border: solid; border-width: 2px;">
 <div id="idContent" style="text-align: left; width:100%; height: 100%">
 </div>
</div>
<div style="text-align: center;"><input id="showContentBtn" type="button" value="Show Content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Added a button in case there was some requirement to get the value for the content and keep those elements in it.

Option 3: If it needs to be inside the iframe, just set url for the above as the src for the iframe.

```html
<html>
<body>
<div style="text-align: center">Edit Frame</div>
<iframe src="/widgets/editor/rich-text" ></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope that this will give you a few ideas you can work with inside your project.